# try to install ubuntu 22.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dell-inspiron

my laptop:Dell inspirsion

OS: Windows 10

Ram:8GB

I try installing in VBOX.

I enable Hardware Virtualization in BIOS.

My problem is that I can't open ubuntu 22.04. The result shows in the image below. After that there is a black screen.
update: add nomodeset in command line. it shows this message
**mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty).**
basic memory is more than 3GB

[image]

Comment: What is the VM Tag?  Are you installing in VBOX?   Did you enable Hardware Virtualization in BIOS?

Comment: yes i enable virtualization. yes i install in vbox through start

Comment: @user19513520 - [Edit] your question instead of clarifying your question with a comment

Comment: I have Ubuntu V22.04 installed and running fine in VMware

Comment: anybody help me plz?

Comment: What installation media are you booting from?  It works just fine for me using the [ISO from Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.04.1&architecture=amd64)

Comment: yes i install from this site.

Comment: Does your Dell have an VT-d setting in addition to Hardware Virtualization?  I do not know about Dell, but check that as I cannot see other reasons for failure to install.

Comment: And just the check first principles in a virtual machine:  (1) Only provide 1 CPU 2 cores max for most guests.  (2) 3 GB of memory is enough for an average guest machine. Do not overpower the guest with hardware resources.   Provide at least 50GB of disk space for your Ubuntu Guest machine.

Comment: @user19513520  ---- Please answer all the points of my last question.

Comment: VT-D must be enable or disable?

Comment: It must be enabled as the Ubuntu guest is most likely 64-bits.

Comment: anybody help me plz?    ----- I do wish you would answer the several questions posted if you want help.